# Wrong route selected in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Could please someone shed some light into this issue, it drives me crazy!

The routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
     "DefaultOrderingRoute", // Route name
     "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{slug}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Order", slug = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
     new { controller = "^Order$" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
      "DefaultImageRoute", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Image", }, // Parameter defaults
      new { controller = "^Image$" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
      "FooterRoute", //route for invoking actions for the Footer
      "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Footer", }, // Parameter defaults
      new { controller = "^Footer$" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
       "DefaultDealRoute", // Route name
       "{city}/{category}/{id}/{slug}", // URL with parameters
       new { category = Deals.Globals.Global.CATEGORY_ALL_NAME, controller = "Deal", action = "Details", slug = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
       new { controller = "^Deal$", id = @"\d+" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "DealRouteForCategory", // Route name
        "{city}/{category}", // URL with parameters
        new { city = "", category = Deals.Globals.Global.CATEGORY_ALL_NAME, controller = "Deal", action = "Details" }, // Parameter defaults   
        new { controller = "^Deal$" }
    );
}
```

I have add a reference to routedebugger to see what is going on under the hood.
So for the selected URL:

http://my.SERVER.IP/VirtualDirectoryName/Order/PayPalNotify/9/blabla

the URL debugger shows the following:

AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath: ~/Order/PayPalNotify/9/adfaf   (exactly what i have expected)!!!

The debugger also shows that routes DefaultOrderingRoute and DefaultDealRoute are matched (this i didn't expect! since i have constraints on the routes!!).

It also shows that the matched route is:

Matched Route: {controller}/{action}/{id}/{slug}

with route data:

```
controller:  Deal
action:      Details
id:          9
slug:        adfaf
city:        Athens
category:    All
```

How is this possible?? What am i doing wrong?

PS. I've noticed that by **reissuing** the URL the correct route gets executed!!!

Comment: Why don't you have `{controller}` and `{action}` on your default deal route? Have you tried moving that route to the top of the list? As routing will match on the first route it can satisfy.

Comment: @mattytommo The problem is that routing does show up the correct url relative part (/Order/PayPalNotify/9/blabla), BUT tokenizing this yields in something totaly different (see table with values). This is what drives me crazy! The order of routes should be always from the more specific route to the more general route (this is what i'm practicing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved: i was doing something very bad(!):

in Session_Start() i had somewhere code which did the following (amongst others)

```
    Session_Start() 
    {
// code snippet out for brevity 
//setup the city route values
    HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["city"] = cityToBeginWith;
//setup the category route values
    HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["category"] = Deals.Globals.Global.CATEGORY_ALL_NAME;
//setup the controller route values
    HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Deal";
//setup the action route values
    HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Details";    
    }
```

This caused the selection of the "false" route... very bad!!